# Добавление к значению переменную или дополнительное значение

Tags: jquery, php, javascript

```
<?php
echo '<table width="auto"><tbody>'; 
if ($res = q("SELECT id_genre,title_genre_book from genre_book")) {
    for($i=1;$i<=mysqli_num_rows($res);$i++){
    while($pole = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
    echo '<tr width="140" style="float:left;"><td width="120px" style="vertical-align:top;"><label for="genre_book"><input type="checkbox" name="genre[]" value="'.$pole['id_genre'].'" id="genre_book" />'.$pole['title_genre_book'].'</label></td></tr>';
    }}
    echo '</tbody></table>';
    echo '<br/>';
}
?>
```

Цель у меня была: Повесить событие  на `label` и пересчитав `checkbox` у `input`, изменить цвет у чекнутой `checkbox`.
Проблема : Оказалось,что при выводе данных на экран у `label for='genre_book'`, а так же `input id='genre_book'` одинаковы во всех 10 `checkbox`...
Вопрос: Как сделать так, чтоб `label for='genre_book'`, а так же `input id='genre_book'` стали разными?
Например: `label for='genre_book1'`, а так же `input id='genre_book1'`, `label for='genre_book2'`, а так же `input id='genre_book2'` и так до десяти..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно, например, добавить к genre_book значение id_genre.

```
echo '<tr width="140" style="float:left;"><td width="120px" style="vertical-align:top;"><label for="genre_book'.$pole['id_genre'].'"><input type="checkbox" name="genre[]" value="'.$pole['id_genre'].'" id="genre_book'.$pole['id_genre'].'" />'.$pole['title_genre_book'].'</label></td></tr>';
```